# Trouble understanding unknown probability distributions

Tags: probability, logic

When reading about random algorithms and probability, I encountered a problem that stated "**a positive number $x$ is chosen at random using an unknown probability distribution**"

Now, I believe that the whole highlighted sentence is contradictory, since a number can not be "chosen" without knowing the probability distribution.

Even assuming that the sentence is valid, the most logical scenario to me would be that all numbers should have equal probability of being selected. However, we know that such uniform probability distribution does not exist over the set of natural numbers, since it would contradict the third axiom of probability.

Again, my question is whether the quoted sentence is a valid (logical) mathematical statement or not.

Comment: There exist valid probability distributions.  You agree with that statement, yes?  I as an interested third party can choose one of these available probability distributions in some way... for example I can pick the standard normal distribution.  I can then select an $x$ in accordance with the probability distribution I had selected.  I can then inform you of the value of $x$ that I selected without informing you of the distribution I had used.

Comment: The distribution is only "*unknown*" to the reader, but not unknown to some facilitator.

Comment: Let me use an example to illustrate my point. Assume that the question continues to ask what is the expected value of x modulo 5? How would you consider answering such question? If the quoted statement is valid, and we consider that x has in fact been chosen, then we must be able to form a probability distribution for x based on the knowledge that we have. Yet as I mentioned in the question a uniform distribution is not possible, so what is it? Please note that I am not talking about the original distribution that the 3rd party has used to choose x. I am talking about our estimate of what x is

Comment: "*Assume the question continues to ask what is the expected value of x modulo 5?*"  There is no way to answer that as we have no information about the distribution that $x$ was selected from, just that it had been selected.